# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1 error but don't know why

Tags: java

EDIT: Some of you guys suggested me to give a little more information in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31618657/error-when-adding-int-to-arraylist?noredirect=1#comment51187436_31618657 , so here goes!

So basically I’m writing a program for school, a dice-program. You should be able to pick how many people that are playing and how many dices that should be used. This information should then be logged to a TextArea, and this I have managed to do and it works great! Here is where things get tricky for me; In the program there should also be a TextArea to which the highscore(s) of each round are logged, and the winner of each round should be printed out on a label. I thought I had solved these problems, but when I try and run the program I get an error and the highscores neither the winner are printed out. Here is my code, I walk you through it!

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.ArrayList;

private void btnPlayActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
    int numberofdices = Integer.parseInt(comboboxnumberOfDices.getSelectedItem().toString());
    int numberofplayers = Integer.parseInt(comboboxnumberOfPlayers.getSelectedItem().toString());
    int randomNumber;
    int playerHighscore = 0;
    int intWinner = 0;
    String strWinner = " ";

    int P1Points;
    int P2Points;
    int P3Points;
    int P4Points;

    int[] numberOfPlayers = new int[numberofplayers];
    int[] numberOfDices = new int[numberofdices];
    ArrayList<Integer> Points = new ArrayList<>();
    int intPlayerPoints = 0;

    Random randomGenerator = new Random();

    lblWinner.setText(” ”);
    txtaResult.setText("");
    txtaResult.append(”The Dice has been thrown\n\n");

    for (int n = 1; n <= numberOfPlayers.length; n++) {
        txtaResult.append(”Player " + n + ":\n");
        for (int m = 1; m <= numberOfDices.length; m++) {
            randomNumber = randomGenerator.nextInt(5)+1;
            txtaResult.append(”Dice " + m + ” gets value " + randomNumber + "\n");
            intPlayerPoints = intPlayerPoints + randomNumber;
        }
        txtaResult.append("Total score: " + intPlayerPoints + "\n\n”);

    //Here’s where things starts to go wrong...
        Integer playerPoints = new Integer(intPlayerPoints);
        Points.add(playerPoints);
        intPlayerPoints = 0;
    }
    playerHighscore = Points.get(0);

    P1Points = Points.get(0);
    P2Points = Points.get(1);
    P3Points = Points.get(2);
    P4Points = Points.get(3);

    for (int i = 0; i < Points.size(); i++) {
        if (Points.get(i) > playerHighscore) {
            playerHighscore = Points.get(i);
        } 
    }
    if (playerHighscore == P1Points) {
        strWinner = ”Player 1 won!";
        intWinner = playerHighscore;
    } else if (playerHighscore == P2Points) {
        strWinner = ”Player 2 won!";
        intWinner = playerHighscore;
    } else if (playerHighscore == P2Points) {
        strWinner = ”Player 3 won!";
        intWinner = playerHighscore;
    } else if (playerHighscore == P4Points) {
        strWinner = ”Player 4 won!";
        intWinner = playerHighscore;
    }
    lblWinner.setText(" " + strWinner);
    txtaHighscore.append(" " + intWinner + "\n");
}
```

Alright, so the first section, until the "Here’s where things starts to go wrong…”-comment is variable declarations and the code that works as I want it to. In the for-loops I first loop through the number of persons playing and then the number of dices they play with. The value of the dices played with during one persons ”turn" are added up in the `intPlayerPoints`-variable and the idea is then, when the second for-loop is done, to store this value in the `Points`-ArrayList. (And then to do the same for each person playing). The value of `intPlayerPoints` is then set to zero.

I then store the different values of the ArrayList in different variables to know which value corresponds to which player, before I use the for-loop right below to figure out the highest value and store it in `playerHighscore`. Finally I use an if-statement to decide which player the `playerHighscore`-variable belongs to and then printing this out.

Now, the problem is that nothing below the ”Here’s were everything starts to go wrong comment…” gets printed out (or, the two last lines does not get printed out) when I push the ”Play”-button, but the rest of the program work as expected, and I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:635)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
    at mainFrame.MainFrame.btnPlayActionPerformed(MainFrame.java:435)
    at mainFrame.MainFrame.access$000(MainFrame.java:14)
    at mainFrame.MainFrame$1.actionPerformed(MainFrame.java:198)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6516)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6281)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4872)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:747)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:704)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:720)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:718)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:717)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

As I wrote before I edited this post, I thought the fault in my code was this line:

`Points.add(playerPoints);`

Since someone who got the same error as me had this kind of problem according to google, but that’s only guessing and that might not be it. I would therefore be very thankful for any help!:)

Comment: You don't need to guess, the Stacktrace (https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stacktrace) tells you which line. In the Wikipedia example it would be line 17 from `TestTry.Java`.

Comment: Also, you should be editing the same question if more information is asked. Not ask a new one.

Comment: What is the Points class? Or is that a member Variable? Classes should be start uppercase, variables lowercase: java naming conventions

Comment: Please show us the complete stacktrace.

Comment: @DanielHári `Points` is an `ArrayList`, look at line 19.

Comment: Thank you all for your help so far!

Comment: This is your line from stacktrace:
at mainFrame.MainFrame.btnPlayActionPerformed(MainFrame.java:435). Line 435 check which statement is that.

Comment: This exception come from one of the Points.get(.... indexed statement, not add. The stacktrace shows you. But you know the exact line numbering

Comment: Put breakpoint on code and go step by step, and check variable states till exception.

Answer (score 1):

You stacktrace is saying that one of the `Points.get` calls is failing because you are attempting to get the 2nd element of a one element list.

Figuring out why is difficult because (frankly) your code is a shambles.  However, my best guess is as follows:

1. This statement is setting the number of players to 1:

   ```
   int numberofplayers = Integer.parseInt(
       comboboxnumberOfPlayers.getSelectedItem().toString());
   ```
2. The loop where you initialize `Points` is calling `add` once, so you are getting a list with one element.
3. Then you do this:

   ```
   P2Points = Points.get(1);
   ```

   which is going to thrown an exception, 'cos there is no such element.

---

So what is wrong with your code to cause these bugs:

1. The code where you are getting the number of players smells wrong to me.  Using `toString` like that could be dangerous, depending on how the combo box was populated.  At any rate, it is giving you the answer "one player" ...
2. This code is definitely wrong:

   ```
   P1Points = Points.get(0);
   P2Points = Points.get(1);
   P3Points = Points.get(2);
   P4Points = Points.get(3);
   ```

   It assumes that there are 4 players, but the actual number of players could be less ... or more.  This is a BUG.

More generally, I said that your code is "a shambles"<sup>1</sup>.  What I mean that it is that there is no sign of a plan in the code.  You have arrays declared that are essentially redundant.  You can't make up your mind if there are 4 players or N players.

Finally, declaring a variable with a name that starts with an upper-case letter is a **major Java style violation**.  If I was marking this code, you would lose all style points for that.  Immediately.

---

<sup>1 - This is the origin of that word ... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Shambles</sup>